# Combining and checking table value on SQL (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

Table 1

```
no name col1
1   a    a_1
2   b    b_1
```

Table 2

```
id   name parent
a_1   zz   c_1
b_1   yy   d_1
c_1   aa   null
d_1   bb   e_1
e_1   dd1  null
```

what i want to show is showing the all list name. for example table 1 name `a` has col1 name `a_1` it will show the name on table 2, and then check the parent in the table 2 and show it and keep checking until it found null. the example is like below.. im sorry for my bad explanation

```
t1_name     t2_name  t2_name   t2_name
   a          zz        aa
   b          yy        bb        dd1
```

or shows like below

```
t1_name     t2_name
   a         aa/zz        
   b       dd1/bb/yy
```

what I've done is this query

```
select t1.name,t2.name as folder from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2 on t1.col1=t2.id
```

and I don't know how to check again in query... I am using oracle `version  12.2.0.1.0` in SQL developer any help?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: im sorry i forgot its oracle @jarlh

Comment: As you cannot have a variable number of columns in the select list, you will have to either use the [sys_connect_by_path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH.html#GUID-D25A0F86-B559-4090-9164-7A2C84D1E11E)  function, or pivot/unpivot with xml

Comment: Did you try with a `connect by prior t2.parent = t2.id` to connect all the rows hierarchically?

Comment: @Viorel i tried but nothing happens.. and i don't know how to fix it... I'm new to this.. i tried something like this `select name from table2 where parent=id`

Comment: I am curious about that but I don't understand how to implement that! @gsalem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to get the rows from the first table and then recursively fetch all the rows from the second table until you reach a null parent, so you do:

```
with cte(NAME,
PARENT,
CURRENTPATH) as
 (select t1.NAME,
         t2.PARENT,
         t2.NAME   as CURRENTPATH
  from   TABLE1 t1
  join   TABLE2 t2 on t1.COL1 = t2.ID
  union all
  select t1.NAME,
         t2.PARENT,
         t1.CURRENTPATH || '/' || t2.NAME as CURRENTPATH
  from   cte t1
  join   TABLE2 t2 on t2.ID = t1.PARENT)
select NAME,
       CURRENTPATH
from   cte
where  PARENT is null;
```

Comment: `number of WITH clause column names does not match number of elements in select list` why i get this error? can you help me? thank you for ur response btw :)

Comment: Interesting, you probably modified the query and either the aliases of the columns in both queries don't match or the list of aliases defined is the CTE does not match. For example `CTE(col1, col3) as (select col1, col2 union all select col1, col2)` or `CTE(col1, col2, col3) as (select col1, col2 union all select col1, col2, col3)` would give such an error. @stephen-090

Comment: Here is a [fiddle with your example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0f87a76deb4da54eb5caf53feb82095e). The query is at the end.

Comment: what if I add 1 more column in table 1 to show, for example, the table 1 consists `no, name,col1, and version` now I want to show version too.. is it just add t1.version to the query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `hierarchical` query as following:

> ```
> SQL> -- Your data
> SQL> with table1(no,name,col1) as
>   2  (SELECT 1, 'a','a_1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
>   3  SELECT 2, 'b','b_1' FROM DUAL
>   4  ),
>   5  table2 (id, name, parent) as
>   6  (select 'a_1', 'zz', 'c_1' from dual union all
>   7  select 'b_1', 'yy', 'd_1' from dual union all
>   8  select 'c_1', 'aa', null from dual union all
>   9  select 'd_1', 'bb', 'e_1' from dual union all
>  10  select 'e_1', 'dd1', null from dual)
>  11  -- Your query starts from here
>  12  SELECT
>  13      T1.NAME    AS T1_NAME,
>  14      T2.NAMES   AS T2_NAMES
>  15  FROM TABLE1 T1
>  16      JOIN (
>  17          SELECT
>  18              T2.ID,
>  19              SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(T2.NAME, '/') AS NAMES,
>  20              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) AS L
>  21          FROM TABLE2 T2
>  22          CONNECT BY T2.PARENT = PRIOR T2.ID
>  23      ) T2 ON T1.COL1 = T2.ID
>  24  WHERE L = 1;
>
> T1_NAME T2_NAMES
> ------- ---------------
> a       /aa/zz
> b       /dd1/bb/yy
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: thank you for your response. from those queries if I have 1000 data, therefore I need to add 1000 data to the syntax query?

Comment: No, You don't need to add data in the query. You will use direct tables. I have used CTE to generate sample data. You must use the query that is after **-- Your query starts from here**

Answer (score 0):

Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: 12.2.0.1.0 version